# I am doing a shopping list, delete ... I do not know how to add the element "li" inside of the "div" with the button (.delete) please check my code

Tags: javascript

I am building a To Do List app, and I want the app to work in such a way that when the 'task' is entered and saved, the entered task will appear on a list with a checkbox, a delete button, and an edit button. I tried appending the child elements on their parent element using .appendchild() but it's not working.

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("#lista");

function inputlength() {
    return input.value.length;
} 

function addLiAfterAction() {  var li = document.createElement("div");
ul.appendChild(li);
li.className= "divlist";
li.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));

input.value ="";
li.appendChild(document.createElement("button")).className= "delete";
   
}

 button.addEventListener("click", function() {
     if( inputlength() > 0) {
        addLiAfterAction();
     }
 })



input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (inputlength() > 0 && event.keyCode ===13) {
        addLiAfterAction();
    }
})



<ul id="lista">
        <div class="divlist"><li>Banana</li><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
        <div class="divlist"><li>apple</li><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
        <div class="divlist"><li>fuji</li><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
        <div class="divlist"><li>Apple blue</li><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
        <div class="divlist"><li>Orange</li><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
```

Comment: Side note, your HTML is invalid. A `<div>` cannot be a child of a `<ul>`, only an `<li>` can

Comment: I believe I came up with a working solution for your problem here: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/GRryeao?editors=1010 Let me know if that is working for you.

Comment: Thank you All! Great Ideas!, I fixed it.  Cheers!